# While Loop Printing Inclusive One Number Per Line JAVA

Tags: java, while-loop

I’ve been trying to write a while loop in Java that should print the numbers *50 to -50 inclusive* one number per line but I don’t understand what i’m doing wrong, here’s my code:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = -50;
        while (count <= 50)
        {
            System.out.println(count);
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Typo. `while (count <= 50);` -- remove the semicolon. That terminates the loop body. Oh, and one line answer `IntStream.rangeClosed(-50, 50).forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: You've got an extra semicolon at the end of the line with the `while`.  Remove it.

Comment: @user1777 was my solution below acceptable as an answer for you?

Answer (score 0):

This is the algorithm you are looking for:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = -50; // initialize a value to start at outside the loop

        while (count <= 50){ // declare a sentinel value
            System.out.println(count);  // println prints each number on their own lines
            count = count + 1; // increment the value to get closer to the sentinel
        }

    }
}
```

You can find more information [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-while-loop-with-examples/) on while-loops

You're initial post was correct, but you had a few syntax errors which probably caused you the problems.